# Is there a name for the type of grouped list used for iPhone contacts?

Tags: lists, controls, iphone

I use iPhone contacts as an example but you see it everywhere.

The sort of list I'm talking about is where the group header (e.g. in the contacts example "S" ) docks to the top of the list while you scroll through all the S's then gets pushed off the top of the list as you get to the T group header which in turns docks to the top of the screen.

Is this just a fancy grouped list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the developer documentation of apple: The groups are called sections, and they are used within a plain table.

So to use Apple developer language I would say it's a **plain table view with indexed sections**. Not a very nice name, but a precise one :-)

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableView_iPhone.pdf (page 14)

Comment: I sort of guessed there wouldn't be specific name.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Indexed list" is what I've heard used.